# Making sense of full text boolean mode results

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, booleanquery

I've been playing around with `boolean mode` with MySQL's `fulltext` searching but I'm not understanding the results I am getting at times.

For example, here are some data rows..

```
auction_id,'name'
100543,'2011-12 Fleer Retro patch auto'
100544,'2011-12 Fleer Retro patch auto jordan'
100545,'2011-12 Fleer Retro autograph'
100546,'2011-12 Fleer Retro autographed'
100547,'2011-12 Fleer Retro auto'
100549,'1999 jordan auto'
100550,'1999 auto jordan'
100551,'1999 autograph jordan'
100552,'1999 autographed jordan patch'
100553,'1999 jordan non auto'
```

Now if I run the query:

```
SELECT auction_id,NAME,description FROM auctions WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST('+jordan +auto' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I get the rows `100544,100549,100550,100553` returned, which is correct. However if I run this query:

```
SELECT auction_id,NAME,description FROM auctions WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST('+jordan +auto -non' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I get the same results returned; shouldn't `100553` go away since it has "non" in the `name`?

Additionally if I change it to:

```
SELECT auction_id,NAME,description FROM auctions WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST('+jordan +auto -"non auto"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I get no results returned; should I get them all except for `100553`?

Answer (score 1):

As documented under [Boolean Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-boolean.html):

> Boolean full-text searches have these characteristics:
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> - The minimum and maximum word length full-text parameters apply: [`innodb_ft_min_token_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size) and [`innodb_ft_max_token_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_max_token_size) for `InnoDB` search indexes, and [`ft_min_word_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) and [`ft_max_word_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_max_word_len) for `MyISAM` ones.

As documented under [Natural Language Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-natural-language.html):

> Some words are ignored in full-text searches:
>
> - Any word that is too short is ignored. The default minimum length of words that are found by full-text searches is three characters for `InnoDB` search indexes, or four characters for `MyISAM`. You can control the cutoff by setting a configuration option before creating the index: [`innodb_ft_min_token_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size) configuration option for `InnoDB` search indexes, or [`ft_min_word_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) for `MyISAM`.

Comment: I just checked my `ft_min_word_len` and it was already set to `2`.

Comment: I believe I changed it quite some time back, before this database was even built. To make sure I just rebuilt the index and still got the same results.

Comment: @Brett: "non" is a [stopword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-stopwords.html).